# Unable to change text between span with Selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am automating a web process, but ran into an issue where I have an html form with drop down buttons. I am unable to drop down the buttons and change the value. I thought of telling selenium to change the text between span tags eg. `<span>SomeText</span>` since that's where the value will change with the drop down button. Problem is all the tags are named same and I don't know how to tell selenium how to change all the values. I only can prefill the input box.
I tried css selectors, find_by_name or class, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use below xpath to click dropdown first and then click on the element based on text.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@data-field-name='stage']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='chosen-results']//li[contains(.,'Closed')]"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that! Something similar I tested. But when I try your code, It clicks where drop down menu happens, but it seems not to find the span text.
 ```raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:```

Comment: @uzdisral : Instead of clickable can you check `presence_of_element_located` located I have updated that let me know how this goes?

Comment: I just did, I get the same message. I just added another picture, if it helps. The values are there in the grey text (maybe hidden)?. But looks like I could choose by index what to click?

Comment: Yes, that worked :D I thought it can't be done. Thanks a lot, great help!

Comment: this is random question, but Can I use `WebDriverWait` to also clear values from the enter fields? Let's say there is a `<span>SomeText</span>` which looks like a box with text and I am able to delete that with backspace. See picture above, eg: email get autopopulated

Comment: If it is an input field yes you can clear the field.WebdriverWait is an explicit wait which wait for an time span to identify the element.

Comment: ok I think that would be a different topic then. As it may be little bit confusing